# show div where its element has attribute title = value

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to show a "`<div class="bundle--form">`" where his child has tag  with attr. **title = productTrim** variable.
here is a demo:

```js
$(function() {
        $('.icon--drop').click(function (event) {
            // The URL changed...
            console.log("url changed");
            
            var productName = $('.super-color-variant[style="display: block;"] .product--title').text();
            var productTrim = $.trim(productName);

            var BundleName = $(`.bundle--product-name a[title='${productTrim}']`).attr('title');
            console.log(productTrim);
            console.log("and");
            console.log(BundleName);

            if(productTrim === BundleName){
                $('.bundle--form').hide()
                $(".bundle--form").find(`div a[title='${productTrim}']`).show();
                console.log("are same")
            }else{
                $('.bundle--form').hide()
                console.log("are not same")
            }
        });
        
});
```

```css
svg#Ebene_1{
  width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.demo{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="super-color-variant" data-super-variant="magenta" style="display: block;">
<h1 class="product--title" itemprop="name">
Toner magenta ersetzt Lexmark 700X3
</h1>
</div>

<a href="#magenta" class="color-drop-link selected _1" data-super-variant="magenta" title="black">
<i class="icon--drop magenta">
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 119.39 130">
<path class="cls-1" d="M75.67,41.8,58.87,10.42,42.06,41.8C33.2,58.43,24.75,70.71,24.75,86.24c0,20.13,17.65,33.35,34.12,33.35S93,106.32,93,86.24C93,70.71,84.54,58.43,75.67,41.8Z"></path>
</svg>
</i>
</a>
<div class="bundle--form">
  <div class="demo">
    <div class="bundle--product-name">
    <a href="#" title="Toner magenta ersetzt Lexmark 700X3">1x Toner magenta ersetzt Lexmark 700X3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bundle--form">
  <div class="demo">
    <div class="bundle--product-name">
    <a href="#" title="original yellow ersetzt Lexmark 700X7">1x original yellow ersetzt Lexmark 700X7</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

basically, when you click on the color drop, only the bundle--form that matches the title should be shown. how can I do that? I've tried many ways, can anyone link an article or give a suggestion? jq or js no problem, thanks :).

Comment: So what exactly about this is not working as intended? // The fact that you are triggering the whole thing on `popstate` makes it rather hard to test here via a snippet, preferably you could rewrite this to a [mre] that uses click events or something.

Comment: ah sorry for that, i will make it on click. ty

Comment: i changed it to click, basically after hiding both divs with class="bundle--form", it needs to show one bundle--form that has "<a title="Toner magenta ersetzt Lexmark 700X3"></a>"

Comment: `$('.bundle--form').hide(); $(".bundle--form").find(`div a[title='${productTrim}']`).show();` - that can't work. If you hide the whole `.bundle--form` element to begin with, then there is little point in trying to show something _inside_ that element again.

Comment: so how can i only show one div element and hide the rest where "title" doesnt match the value ?

Comment: You need to go from the link that you found, back up to the `.bundle--form` ancestor again, to make _that_ show again: `$(".bundle--form").find(\`div a[title='${productTrim}']\`).parents('.bundle--form').show();`

Comment: @CBroe thank you very much , ic an accept your answer if u write it as an answer. youre a legend <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell jQuery to show the `a` tag within a `.bundle--form`. But the `.bundle--form` is not shown and thus the browser will not render anything in it.

I believe you meant to show the `.bundle-form` where the `a` tag with that specific title is in.

I changed this:

```js
$(".bundle--form").find(`div a[title='${productTrim}']`).show();
```

to this:

```js
$(`.bundle--form a[title='${productTrim}']`).closest('.bundle--form').show();
```

jQuery uses the recently selected element. What you call show on was the `a` tag, when in fact you probably wanted the closest `.bundle--form`.
See updated snippet below.

```js
$(function() {
        $('.icon--drop').click(function (event) {
            // The URL changed...
            console.log("url changed");
            
            var productName = $('.super-color-variant[style="display: block;"] .product--title').text();
            var productTrim = $.trim(productName);

            var BundleName = $(`.bundle--product-name a[title='${productTrim}']`).attr('title');
            console.log(productTrim, "and", BundleName);

            if(productTrim === BundleName){
                $('.bundle--form').hide()
                $(`.bundle--form a[title='${productTrim}']`).closest('.bundle--form').show();
                console.log("are same")
            }else{
                $('.bundle--form').hide()
                console.log("are not same")
            }
        });
        
});
```

```css
svg#Ebene_1{
  width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.demo{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="super-color-variant" data-super-variant="magenta" style="display: block;">
<h1 class="product--title" itemprop="name">
Toner magenta ersetzt Lexmark 700X3
</h1>
</div>

<a href="#magenta" class="color-drop-link selected _1" data-super-variant="magenta" title="black">
<i class="icon--drop magenta">
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 119.39 130">
<path class="cls-1" d="M75.67,41.8,58.87,10.42,42.06,41.8C33.2,58.43,24.75,70.71,24.75,86.24c0,20.13,17.65,33.35,34.12,33.35S93,106.32,93,86.24C93,70.71,84.54,58.43,75.67,41.8Z"></path>
</svg>
</i>
</a>
<div class="bundle--form">
  <div class="demo">
    <div class="bundle--product-name">
    <a href="#" title="Toner magenta ersetzt Lexmark 700X3">1x Toner magenta ersetzt Lexmark 700X3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bundle--form">
  <div class="demo">
    <div class="bundle--product-name">
    <a href="#" title="original yellow ersetzt Lexmark 700X7">1x original yellow ersetzt Lexmark 700X7</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```